# prerty print jq bash

Tags: bash, jq

I need to print a json file in bash in a way that each element of the file fits in one line.

There are a couple of elements with many caracters and when I print it they take several lines.

I would like find a way that bash prints the begining + $. Dollar sign means there is aditional text not being displayed.

Thanks for your help.

Gerard

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 0):

This script does this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

LEN=$1

# If no length has been provided as argument,
# using the terminal width-1 as default.
if [[ -z $LEN ]]; then
    LEN=$(tput cols)
    let LEN=LEN-1
fi

IFS=''
while read LINE; do
    [[ ${#LINE} -ge $LEN ]] && LINE="${LINE:0:$LEN}$"
    echo "$LINE"
done < /dev/stdin
```

Save it as `trim.sh` and use like this:

```sh
jq . your.json | ./trim.sh 25
```

The argument value of 25 is desired length. Omit it to use the terminal window width as default.

The only caveat is disabled color output from `jq`. You can force enable it with `-C` argument to `jq`, but it screws script's output. Not sure how to fix.